# How to fixed a button inside containers?

Tags: html, css

I have a button inside the header menu , That header contains the logo & social media icons & that button.

I want to make that button fixed , So that when I scroll it's always at the top of the screen.

Let's say I have the following html code:

```css
.menu{background:#ddd}

.logo,
.social-media,
.sticky-container{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%
}

.logo{background:#000}

.social-media{background:#080}

.sticky-container{background:#333}

.logo,
.sticky-container{color:#fff}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="logo">Logo</div>
      <div class="social-media">
        <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
        <div class="youtube">Youtube</div>
        <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sticky-container">
        <a class="sticky-element">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the button with class `sticky-element` that is inside `sticky-container` to be sticky.

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: fixed;` for your `sticky-container` class.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30shhy3L/2/

**Edit:**

From comments, as you have mentioned your real site at https://logosperformance.com, just change the css of `[data-css="tve-u-163a8211f58"]` element as following:

```
[data-css="tve-u-163a8211f58"] {
    float: right;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -2px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: It's not working on the website , Could you please try? www.bit.ly/2IXSGQC

Comment: @Frank It's working for your real site, too. I've tested.

Comment: What browser are you using ? , I tried it and the button still on the header and is not sticky

Comment: I've tested it in firefox

Comment: But it should be cross browser compatibility

Comment: No it isn't any cross browser issue, you are placing css inside wrong element, please check carefully. The solution was pretty simple and straightforward.